# Alchemy4Tridion plugin with internationalization

Tags: a4t

I'm developing my first Alchemy4Tridion Plugin for SDL Tridion 2013, but I'm facing some challenges.

In my solution, I added resource files (.resx) to the App_GlobalResources folder. However, these files are not included in the .a4t file as a result of the build. Neither are the *.resources.dll files.

Is there some way to configure the a4t plugin to include *.resx and *.resources.dll files and to deploy those automatically to /web/WebUI/WebRoot/App_GlobalResources and /web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin respectively, when I drag & drop the plugin?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not yet supported by Alchemy. I entered an issue about using string resources a little while ago: [Support for string resources in ASPX and JavaScript](https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/issues/122)

The issue is still open, so it looks like we'll have to wait a little longer for that feature :)